# Open and update CSV file

Tags: python, python-3.x, object-oriented, csv

```
import csv
class CSV:  
    def __init__(self,title, row=[]):
       self.row = row
       self.title = title

    def create(self):
       csvfilename = "{}".format(self.title)
       csvFileObj = open(csvfilename, 'w' , encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='')
       csvWriterObj = csv.writer(csvFileObj) 
       csvWriterObj.writerow(self.row)
       csvFileObj.close()

    def createConsolidate(self):
       csvfilename = "{}".format(self.title)
       csvFileObj = open(csvfilename, 'w' , encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='')
       csvWriterObj = csv.writer(csvFileObj)  
       for row in self.row:
          csvWriterObj.writerow(row)
       csvFileObj.close()

    def appendConsolidate(self): 
       csvfilename = "{}".format(self.title)
       csvFileObj = open(csvfilename, 'a' , encoding='utf-8-sig', newline='')
       csvWriterObj = csv.writer(csvFileObj)  
       for row in self.row:
          csvWriterObj.writerow(row)
       csvFileObj.close()

    def open(self):.
       rowData = []
       csvfilename = "{}".format(self.title)
       csvFileObj = open(csvfilename, encoding='utf-8-sig')
       readerObj = csv.reader(csvFileObj)
       for row in readerObj:
         rowData.append(row)
       return rowData
       csvFileObj.close()
```

It's working but not DRY. It can be easy to make it just a function, but for learning purposes, I used Python classes am not familiar with them.

Answer (score 1):

### Overview

The code layout is pretty good, and you used meaningful names for the class,
and some of the functions and variables.

### Syntax error

The code does have a syntax error, but I assume there was a simple copy and paste
issue when you copied the code into the question.  The `.` does not belong
at the end of this line:

```
def open(self):.
```

### Documentation

You should add documentation to the top of your file to state the purpose
of the code.  The [PEP 8](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008) style guide
recommends that you add docstrings for your methods.

### Naming

The `open` function name is not very meaningful since all your functions
open a file.  It also has the same name as Python built-in function.  Choose
a more specific name.

It seems like `file_name` would be a better variable name than `title`.

### [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)

There is no need for every function to have a separate `csvfilename`.
Simply use the class variable `self.file_name`.

Add a class variable for the same `"utf-8-sig"` string used by all functions.

### Lint check

[pylint](https://docs.pylint.org/index.html) identified a few style issues.

Consider using `with` for the calls to `open`.  Then you don't need to
call `close`.  For example:

```
def create(self):
    with open(self.file_name, "w", encoding="utf-8-sig", newline="") as csvFileObj:
        csvWriterObj = csv.writer(csvFileObj)
        csvWriterObj.writerow(self.row)
```

There is inconsistent indentation.  PEP-8 recommends 4 spaces per level.
You can use the [black](https://pypi.org/project/black) program to automatically
modify the code for you.

PEP-8 also recommends you delete trailing whitespace.  Again, `black` can be used.